# C++ data members return garbage after being defined in a separate member function

Tags: c++, class, member

I don't know how much of the below code is relevant to the problem, but I have a derived class with three data members (`loc`, `remote_host`, and `remote_port`). They're being declared in the class' header file, and being defined in the `Initialize()` member function. However, when the `HandleRequest()` function tries to access them, `remote_host` and `remote_port` return garbage and 0 respectively; `loc` returns `"/proxy"` as expected. Can someone point out the obvious? I'm lost here...

```
// in response_handler.hh
class ResponseHandlerInterface {
  public:
    virtual bool Initialize(const NginxConfig& config) = 0;
    virtual bool HandleRequest(const std::string& request, std::string* response) = 0;
};


// in ProxyHandler.hh
class ProxyHandler : public ResponseHandlerInterface {
  public:
    std::string loc, remote_host;
    int remote_port;
    bool Initialize(const NginxConfig&);
    bool HandleRequest(const std::string&, std::string*);
};


// in ProxyHandler.cc
bool ProxyHandler::Initialize(const NginxConfig &config) {
  loc = "/proxy";
  remote_host = "digboston.com";
  remote_port = 80;
  std::cout << "Values in Initialize():" << std::endl;
  std::cout << loc << " " << remote_host << " " << remote_port << std::endl;
  return true;
}

bool ProxyHandler::HandleRequest(const std::string &request, std::string *response) {
  std::cout << "Values in HandleResponse():" << std::endl;
  std::cout << loc << " " << remote_host << " " << remote_port << std::endl;
  return true;
}


// in main.cc
  // a new instance of ProxyHandler is created,
  // Initialize() is called on the object,
  // HandleRequest() is called on the object.
```

---

Here is the output :(

```
>> ./runprogram

Values in Initialize():
/proxy digboston.com 80

Values in HandleResponse():
/proxy H?/P??P??    P??@    P??`    P?? 0
```

As you can see, `loc` retained its value. `remote_host` and `remote_port` hold their garbage values from when they were initialized. What can I do to make sure all three values are changed permanently from the `Initialize()` function??

Comment: By the way, I sort of paraphrased, only including relevant code, so as not to make the code snippets unbearably long. If I left something out, or there's a typo, let me know.

Comment: In C++, they're called member functions, not methods.

Comment: Best not to post snippets but to construct a _testcase_, so we can reproduce the problem ourselves and have a play. This is actually a crucial part of debugging so do that before posting. http://sscce.org To be honest I'd expect someone who's been on SO for two years and posted over 40 questions to know this by now.

Comment: what is the NginxConfig parameter used for?   Does the full code some time take values from there?  -- There is clearly something which is overriding your data, but it isnot in the code posted.   I would suggest to run a debugger and set a watch/breakpoint point for whenever the remote_host is changed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the order of instructions if it's truly as you suggest.  Is there other relevant code you've omitted?  When was the last time you cleaned and rebuilt?  Can you show us how the object is instantiated and accessed?

Comment: How is the object getting instantiated and then used?  My shot in the dark is that the variable that you instantiate isn't the same as the one you're printing.  Try printing out the `this` pointer in both printouts to make sure it is the same object.

Comment: @everybody So there's nothing obviously wrong with the code I posted (which is where I thought the problem was)? This code has so many interconnected files, I thought it would be overkill to post several hundred lines of code in the question details.

Comment: @sgarza62 problem is that your code snippet works as it is, i.e. `Initialize` then `HandleRequest` outputs the desired result.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for that link, I'll have a read. And I agree with you...guess we all learn this lesson eventually, and now's my time. Sorry about that guys.

Comment: You don't have to post several hundred lines.  Clearly the object you're calling `HandleResponse` on is either a different object or has been modified since having `Initialize` called on it.  Set a data break point on the object and see if it changes.  If it does, it'll break on the code that changes it.  If it doesn't, then you're not outputting the same object.

Comment: Is there any reason the initialization canot be done in the ctor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the part you left out. There is nothing wrong with what you have, indeed if I implement what you say in your comments then I get the expected output:

```
Values in Initialize():
/proxy digboston.com 80
Values in HandleResponse():
/proxy digboston.com 80
```

My additions are as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

struct NginxConfig {};

// YOUR CODE GOES HERE

int main() {
  ProxyHandler ph;
  ph.Initialize(NginxConfig());
  ph.HandleRequest(std::string(""), NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I also get the same correct output. Probably the OP forgot to `Initialize()` the object, or is deleting it somehow.

Comment: @vsoftco That could be. I'm working within someone else's codebase, and they're using `new` to create an object, but this might be a scope problem. (Although, `loc` is coming up fine).

Comment: @vsoftco Even if you forget `Initialize`, these are `std::string` objects; they have constructors. Anyway, the sample output shows a trace from `Initialize`.

Comment: @Kaz, true, probably the access is done through invalid pointers, but we can only guess from the posted code.

Comment: So, in summary, you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @sgarza62 I highly suspect that it's a case of use after delete, but there are other ways to get a bad pointer. If you get stuck looking at the code you can try using debug tools like `valgrind` or a debug malloc library.